# Nethttp_client.Convenience for https URLs

Tags: ocaml

I am very new to OCaml.  I want to read the html code of a website given a URL using the ocamlnet library.  I want to read the html code from google, and print it out.  Here is what I am trying now:

```
(*Inside ReadWebsite.ml*)
open Printf
open Nethttp_client

let content = Convenience.http_get "https://www.google.com";;
printf "%s\n" content;;
```

Here is how I am compiling:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc ReadWebsite.ml -package netclient -linkpkg -o read
```

There are not compiling errors.  When I run the program, I get the following error message

```
Fatal error: exception Failure("Nethttp_client: No https transport available")
```

So my question is, how should I configure Nethttp_client to work with an https connection?  Here is a link to the Nethttp_client.Convenience documentation http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/ocamlnet-4.0.4/doc/html-main/Nethttp_client.Convenience.html

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Nettls_gnutls.init()` to use GnuTLS as TLS provider:

```
let () =
  Nettls_gnutls.init()
```

and add `nettls-gnutls` package.

```
ocamlfind ocamlc ReadWebsite.ml -package netclient,nettls-gnutls -linkpkg -o read
```

Here is a document about TLS. http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/ocamlnet-4.0.4/doc/html-main/Tls.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried what you proposed, but I'm missing the nettls-gnutls package.  Here is what I tried: 

    ocamlfind: Package `nettls-gnutls' not found

How should I go about getting the nettls-gnutls package?  I tried this:

    opam install conf-gnutls.

But I was missing external dependencies.

Comment: I installed gnutls by `apt install libgnutls28-dev` on debian.